# Allow HTML files in Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an application using ASP.NET MVC and Angular JS.

The point is to use angular for all web things and ASP.Net for backend stuff. In other words, I kind of bypassed the whole view of MVC and used a single view. Angular will get his files from the Content folder.

Those files are .html files and this seem to be a problem because I always get a 404.
Actually I also tried renaming it to .cshtml but that does not fix the problem..

Do you know of any tricks (well, clean ones of course) to let my angular app download it's views and be happy?

Thanks.

Georges

Answer (score 2):

The problem most likely is in the fact that ASP.NET MVC tries to filter the request through the routing mechanism, and obviously there is no route for HTML files. Try adding the following to the routes registration method:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
```

Comment: This would probably work, but I would recommend setting up a controller action that handles your views dynamically.  This is a more ".NET MVC" way of handling things.

Comment: Well... I figured I was just being totally dumb... The url had a typo... It's just totally crazy the time you can loose on such a small thing. Thanks to both of you for looking into this... And sorry for the waste of time...